# Best practice for handling HTTP error call

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, exception

I posted this question to the Android developer groups but I wanted to post it here for other people who might be facing a design problem like me:

I was looking for an idiom or paradigm on how to handle HTTP errors.

Basically,

I have an AsyncTask that runs in a background thread, that calls a static method of mine called executeRequest().

This is all done in the doInBackground() part. There are two types of exceptions that be thrown by executeRequest(). An IOException for all communication errors and a ServerErrorResponse exception which is my own exception. This can occur if for example the client sent something bad to the server, the whole HTTP worked but the server complained (perhaps I passed an invalid parameter or id).

So, what I have done is wrap the result in a "result object" of my own.

In onPostExecute() I check if the result was failed and then I try to handle it in the UI thread. However, I now have to start doing

```
Exception e = result.getException();
if (e != null) {
  if (e instanceof IOException) { //network error
   //handle network error here
 } else if (e instanceof ServerErrorResponseException) {
   //handle server error response here
}
```

As you can see this is becoming annoying, For every new exception I have to check it using instanceof.  Is there a way around it or a design I could follow to avoid this? I want the exceptions to be processed in the UI thread in case I show a dialog box or something to the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Exception e = result.getException();
if (e != null) {
  try {
    throw e;
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    //handle network error here
  } catch (ServerErrorResponseException ex) {
    //handle server error response here
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //handle RuntimeException and others here
    //(You weren't just going to ignore them, were you?)
  }
}
```

Comment: You might also look at the `java.util.concurrent` package's `ExecutorService`. It makes handling exceptions from background tasks very simple; if a task throws an `Exception`, trying to `get()` the result from the associated `Future` throws an exception rather than getting the result. So, your application doesn't have to do an explicit "was there an error" check.

Comment: Yes Androids AsyncTask uses and ExecutorService for this. Let me review some stuff and I will mark this response as the answer. There is no other way you can think of except rethrowing and catching correct?

Comment: It isn't the only way (test with `instanceof` works too), but I think this is the best way. It's a common pattern, used (indirectly) in other APIs.

Answer (score 2):

This is only one option, out of several:

Create an interface like

```
public interface ResultReceiver {
  public void onSuccess(YourClass object);
  public void onError(Exception err);
  //alternatives to the former:
  public void onNetworkError(IOException err); //maybe the parameter is optional?
  public void onServerProblem(ServerErrorResponseException err);
}
```

Now, in your `onPostExecute` do something like

```
result.handleWith(this); //I'm assuming your activity implements ``ResultReceiver`` interface
```

If you prefer, you can create the result handler outside your activity (this option is better in order to avoid code duplication across activities)

Finally, `handleWith` implementation:

```
public void handleWith(ResultReceiver handler){ 
  Exception e = result.getException();
  if (e != null) {
    if (e instanceof IOException) { //network error
     handler.onNetworkError(e);
   } else if (e instanceof ServerErrorResponseException) {
     handler.onServerProblem(e);
  } else {
     handler.onSuccess(this);
  }

}
```

Comment: Pedro, thanks for the response but this is not what I was looking for. I was looking to avoid the pattern of checking what type of error it is by using instanceof all the time. If a new type of exception comes in I have to add another elseif statement and also update the interface.

Comment: Usually, what happens is that I have 3 or 4 cases: Success, NetworkError, ServerError and perhaps an unexpected error. Usually I handle each of these 3 (or 4) cases separately. Further errors should fall into one of these options and in those situations, I send some string or code providing information about which message should be displayed. If you can do this, you won't have to create other types of errors